# Running graylog cluster in docker swarm mode

Tags: docker-swarm-mode, graylog

I have graylog server running as a docker container on my host. Now I want to run a graylog cluster using docker swarm. Is it possible to do it. If possible should i go with an extra load balancer like nginx.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I am running Graylog in a Swarm environment as well. Have you checked https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/graylog/? It has a Docker Compose template which you can adjust to fit your needs and have it deployed with `docker stack deploy`.
You do not need an extra Load Balancer by default, but you can add one, of course. I am using an HAproxy to terminate SSL and proxy requests into the container.

Comment: OK. if a node goes down on graylog cluster. Would the swarm load balancer automatically reroute the application logging(external request to swarm) on to a random node in the cluster? Also if a node goes down on a cluster do swarm load balancer take the node out of the cluster so that application logging would not go on to the node which is already down.

Comment: In Swarm mode, Docker monitors cluster health, so if a node goes down, it starts automatically the crashed containers on online nodes. Ports are accessible on master nodes and then routed to the appropriate workers. However, for safety, you can always add a Load Balancer layer.